# C - Writing a buffer as binary file (wav)

Tags: c, binary, buffer

I am reading a wav file as binary, putting it in a buffer and I want to write the exact same wav file again.

Here is my code so far:

```
file = fopen("tone1.wav", "rb");
file3 = fopen("outout.wav","wb"); 
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
fileLen=ftell(file);
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
buffer=(char *)malloc(fileLen+1);
buffer3=(char *)malloc(fileLen+1);
fread(buffer, fileLen, 1, file);
for (int i=0;i<fileLen+1;++i){
    buffer3[i]=buffer[i];
    fwrite(buffer3,sizeof(buffer3),1,file3);
}
fclose(file);
fclose(file3);
free(buffer);
free(buffer3);
```

The problem is that the outout wav file comes empty and unplayable.
I am not sure what i'm doing wrong. If I replace `fwrite(buffer3,sizeof(buffer3),1,file3);` by `fwrite(buffer3,sizeof(buffer3),1048,file3);` (let's say 1048) I get something playable but not the entire wav with a loop in it.

Can anyone tell me what's the problem? Maybe it's the for loop length that's wrong maybe i shouldn't put fileLen as a limit to it? What should i replace 1 by?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `sizeof(buffer3)` - not doing what you think it is; that's the size of a *pointer*. And I'm not really sure you want that `fwrite` in the loop anyway.

Comment: you're right i replaced it by sizeof(char) but still the same (since my buffers point to chars)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not write inside the loop.
Or write diferent characters every time (not always `buffer3[0]`).

```
fread(buffer, fileLen, 1, file);
for (int i = 0; i < fileLen; ++i) {
    // transform and copy
    buffer3[i] = transform(buffer[i]);
    //fwrite(buffer3 + i, 1, 1, file3); // write 1 character only
}
fwrite(buffer3, fileLen, 1, file3); // write all the new buffer
```

Comment: I understand now. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Please observe the following:

- the fact that the file is "raw" and has a ".wav" extension, as you put it, does neither mean it is a `wav` file nor makes a `wav` file out of it. In order to become a `wav` file it needs a valid WAV header and requires proper audio file API for reading and writing. What you're reading and copying is *headerless* data of unknown format and unknown endianness.
- if you want use to standard library C functions for copying contents from one file to another, you do it on the byte level, without interpreting the content, which is what you do.

In that case, there are few issues in your code:

1. redundant padding of the buffers and casting the return of `malloc` in C:
   `buffer = malloc(fileLen);` should work.
2. ambiguous logic: why do you, upon having read the source file in one pass, both copy buffers and write to the destination file byte-per-byte, inside the loop?
3. even if so, you are still passing incorrect arguments to `fread` and `fwrite` functions, please, check *man* pages. 
   `fread(buffer, 1, fileLen, file);` should fix the read. (`1` equals `sizeof (char)`).
4. why do you need a redundant buffer `buffer3` if you don't interpret the content of file?
5. even if so, you are still passing incorrect arguments to your functions inside the loop. This should do the fix:

   ```
   for (int i=0; i<fileLen; i++){
       buffer3[i]=buffer[i];
       fwrite(&(buffer3[i]),1,1,file3);
   }
   ```

Generally one doesn't know the size of the file in advance, before opening the source file. So one allocates the buffer of reasonable size, then reads and writes in chunks determined by the size of the buffer. In that case your read routine should also handle the buffer underflow condition.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by putting `fwrite(buffer3,sizeof(char),78000,file3);` outside of the for loop, with 78000 being the size of the file1. But my question is, how can i know what is its size by code?

Comment: The size is `fileLen`.